# School & class blogs - renaming/archiving post categories?

Tags: categories

In a small school we use WP to create class-blog posts, therefore each posts may be assigned to a class-blog category representing the class (Year 1, Year 2, etc).
While this was fine until school end, for next year it won't make much sense as students are moving to next-year "classes".

Possible solutions:

1. Delete all last-year class-blog posts
2. Rename old categories to something else such as "2017.18 - Year 1" and create new categories for next year
3. Leave as is

Solution number 2 seems good, but this will make grow the categories list over time and may lead to confusion for teachers creating posts (having to scroll through longer lists of categories)

Your thoughts?

Comment: I think your classes (Year 1) should be different from sessions (2017-2018).

Comment: Great,  I could add a "session" category.....therefore apply filters accordingly, depending on current year or previous years. What do you think?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, create a new taxonomy `session` and use it with `classes`.

In this way you don't have to create each class again and you will be able to differentiate which session (and class) a blog post is linked to.

Example: Create new blog post. Assign it session `2017-2018` and class `year 1`. Now you can query using session and/or class to get desired results.